# Multiple Pattern Match Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, finite-automata

I have lot of logs and every record contains a url. And I have about 2000+ url patterns to filter the log. Some patterns are regular pattern with capturable group. I want to get url and the matched pattern and, if possible, the captured groupes. Is there a java lib can help me. Or any Algorithm which can solve my problem. Or anyting else which related to my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at java regular expressions library ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).

You can construct a single large pattern by concatenating your original patterns with `|` between them (use `()` to specify that you don't want just 1 character).

The regular expression can be compiled into an efficient matching finite automata, that you can run over your data. Just make sure you compile it once and reuse it for every record.

It will handle extracting groups, but you need to handle the groups in a generic way (since any group can be matched). If it makes it easier consider using named groups to make handling simpler.

Comment: I also want get the exactly matched pattern(s), or related info. I didn't found any method to support this with  java regular expressions library.

Comment: Use named groups, or assign your patterns some generated names (i.e. 'pattern_0', 'pattern_1'...). Define them like this `(?<name>X)` to match X with name `name`. Then when you get the results back `Mathcher.group("name")`. You have to iterate through the names you've assigned and request them all. For groups that don't match the function will do a hash lookup and return null (will be fast). This doesn't require to traverse the input string again, so it's still much faster than having separate regex'es for each pattern.